# reading multiple items semi-interactively from the user in bash

Tags: bash, stdin

I'm trying to read multiple items from the user in a shell script, with no luck.  The intention is to read a list of files first (which are read from the stdin pipe), and then read twice more to get two strings interactively.  What I'm trying to do is read a list of files to attach in an email, then the subject and finally the email body.

So far I have this:

```
photos=($(< /dev/stdin))

echo "Enter message subject"
subject=$(< /dev/stdin)

echo "Enter message body"
body=$(< /dev/stdin)
```

(plus error checking code that I omit for succintness)

However, this gets an empty subject and body presumably because the second and third redirections get EOF.

I've been trying to close and reopen stdin with <&- and stuff but it doesn't seem to work that way.

I even tried using a separator for the list of files, using a "while; read line" loop and break out of the loop when the separator was detected.  But that didn't work either (??).

Any ideas how to build something like this?

Comment: You aren't reading stdin multiple times, you're reading the terminal and stdin separately.
The phrasing of the question should be fixed to reflect that so it doesn't mislead people here who think you are actually re-reading stdin.

Comment: The question subject is still "reading stdin multiple times" and that's not the answer you want.  Please change it to something like "read from both stdin and terminal in bash".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Prompt and read two things from the terminal (not from stdin), then read stdin.
# The last line uses arrays, so is BASH-specific.  The read lines are portable.
# - Ian! D. Allen - idallen@idallen.ca - www.idallen.com
read -p "Enter message subject: " subject </dev/tty
read -p  "Enter message body: " body </dev/tty
photos=($(</dev/stdin))
```

Answer (score 6):

So what I ended up doing is based on ezpz's answer and this doc: http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/io-redirection.html  Basically I prompt for the fields first from /dev/tty, and then read stdin, using the dup-and-close trick:

```
# close stdin after dup'ing it to FD 6
exec 6<&0

# open /dev/tty as stdin
exec 0</dev/tty

# now read the fields
echo "Enter message subject"
read subject
echo "Enter message body"
read body

# done reading interactively; now read from the pipe
exec 0<&6 6<&-
photos=($(< /dev/stdin))
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Dennis Williamson had a shorter way, with the addition of `</dev/tty` to the end of the `read` statements.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `read` to prompt for the subject and body:

```
photos=($(< /dev/stdin))

read -rp "Enter message subject" subject

read -rp "Enter message body" body
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works if I am entering the data interactively. However, if I use a pipe (which is what I'm actually interested in), it doesn't. For example, I'm trying to do this:

    cat /tmp/somephotoids | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/DSC_\1.jpg/' | sendpics.sh

While I could workaround the issue by cut'n'pasting, I have spent enough time on doing it this way that I now consider it some sort of challenge.

Comment: All this answer needs is to add `</dev/tty` to the end of each `read` statement, then it's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is possible that you have a varying number of photos, why not just prompt for the known fields first and then read 'everything else'. It is much easier than trying to get the last two fields of an unknown length in an interactive manner.

Comment: The reason that doesn't work for me is that I am trying to use a pipe to pass the list of photos. If I simply read the those fields before the list, the two first photos in the list end up being subject and email body, which is not what I want. (Of course, I could dictate that the subject and body must be passed in the first two lines of the input pipe, but that's much too ugly for me.)