# Bash script pause while command waits for stdin

Tags: bash

I have an endpoint that returns the following plain text:

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -key server.key -out server.csr
```

but after I run it like this:

```
curl -sSf https://.../ | bash -
```

it asks `Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:` but then immediately runs the second command which causes an error and goes back to the prompt. How can I make it wait for the user to enter all the fields asked by command 1 and then run command 2?

The reason I am doing it like this is because I am creating a service that reads plain text from a curl call and pipes it to bash; a sort of automated scripting from a remote resource.

Comment: It would automatically pause for stdin if executed as posted. Maybe you call it in such a way that stdin is not available to be waited on?

Comment: Sorry, I left something important out. Updating the question.

Comment: stdin is consumed by bash in this case. Tell us why you run the script in such a twisted way.

Comment: I actually run it like `curl -sSf https://.../ | bash -` as that is an internal service I created for running automated scripts.

Comment: Use process substitution `bash <(curl blah blah)`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Works perfect. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the content of a script is piped into `bash`, stdin is connected to the pipe rather than the tty, so the script cannot read from a tty, and actually can't milk anything out of stdin for that matter (will always get EOF), because stdin is already exhausted by `bash`. It is possible to exhaust stdin multiple times within the script by closing and reconnecting it (for instance, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992323)), but for any generated script content, you can always use process substitution to free up stdin:

```
bash <(curl -sSL http://git.io/vlhFL)
```

Comment: Thanks, exact solution I needed.